# WPF MVVM Treeview not populating

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

I'm fairly new to MVVM. The rest of my application's contents work fine, except for my treeView, which I can't seem to populate.

I've been using this [example](http://www.technical-recipes.com/2017/using-hierarchicaldatatemplate-with-treeview-in-wpf-mvvm/)

I have a MessageTree object, as below :

```
public class MessageTree
{
    public MessageTree(string message, MessageSeverity severity)
    {
        Message = message;
        MessageSeverity = severity;
    }
    public  MessageSeverity MessageSeverity { get; set; }


    public string Message { get; set; }

    public List<MessageTree> Children { get; set; }

    public MessageTree AddChild(string message, MessageSeverity severity)
    {
        var child = new MessageTree(message, severity);
        return AddChild(child);
    }

    public MessageTree AddChild(MessageTree child)
    {
        if (Children == null)
        {
            Children = new List<MessageTree>();
        }
        Children.Add(child);
        return child;
    }

    public void Add(List<MessageTree> nodes)
    {
        if(Children == null)
        {
            Children = new List<MessageTree>();
        }
        Children.AddRange(nodes);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ToString(0);
    }

    public string ToString(int depth)
    {
        var ret = new StringBuilder();
        ret.Append(new string('\t', depth));
        ret.AppendLine(Message);
        if (Children != null)
        {
            foreach(var child in Children)
            {
                ret.AppendLine(child.ToString(depth + 1));
            }
        }
        return ret.ToString();
    }

    public void ToConsole()
    {
        ToConsole(0);
    }

    public void ToConsole(int depth)
    {
        var tabs = new string('\t', depth);
        Console.WriteLine($"{tabs}{Message}");
        if (Children != null)
        {
            foreach (var child in Children)
            {
                child.ToConsole(depth + 1);
            }
        }
    }

    public MessageSeverity InheritedSeverity
    {
        get
        {
            if (Children == null)
            {
                return MessageSeverity;
            }

            var errors = Children.Where(c => c.InheritedSeverity == MessageSeverity.Error);
            if (errors.Any())
            {
                return MessageSeverity.Error;
            }

            var warnings = Children.Where(c => c.InheritedSeverity == MessageSeverity.Warning);
            if (warnings.Any())
            {
                return MessageSeverity.Warning;
            }

            return MessageSeverity.None;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in my viewModel

```
  private MessageTree _tree;

  public MessageTree Tree
  {
      get => _tree;
      set
      {
          _tree = value;
          OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Tree));
      }
  }

  public void Validate()
  {
      Tree = Validate(Remittance) ?? throw new ArgumentNullException($"Validate(Remittance)");
  }
  ...
```

My view :

```
<UserControl x:Class="ConveyorFrontEnd.Controls.RemittanceValidator"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ConveyorFrontEnd.Controls"
         xmlns:common="clr-namespace:Teragra.Common;assembly=Teragra.Common"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
<Grid>
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Tree}">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type common:MessageTree}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Message}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
    <!--<Button Grid.Column="0" Content="Validate" Command="{Binding Path=ValidateCommand}"/>-->
</Grid>
```

When debugging my project, theTree object gets populated with at least one item, with one element in Children. However, nothing gets displayed on the view, and nothing is displayed in the output. When I change the view's binding to something that doesn't exist, like Binding TreeBreakHere, it specifies that it cant ind TreeBreakHere, so it clearly picks up the binding. I've also changed the textBlock to not be a binding, but to something constant like Text="TextGoesHere", but it still doesn't display anything.

I'm fairly confident that my problem lies with the way I'm trying to specify the structure of my tree, but can't seem to find out where I'm going wrong. Can anyone push me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the ItemSource in the treeView.

I was binding to a single element, like this :

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Tree}">
```

The binding should be to an enumerable, not a single element